# parsing xml using dom4j

Tags: xml, dom4j, yahoo-weather-api

My XML structure is like this:

```
<rss>
     <channel>
         <yweather:location city="Paris" region="" country="France"/>
         <yweather:units temperature="C" distance="km" pressure="mb" speed="km/h"/>
         <yweather:wind chill="-1" direction="40" speed="11.27"/>
         <yweather:atmosphere humidity="87" visibility="9.99" pressure="1015.92" rising="0"/>
         <yweather:astronomy sunrise="8:30 am" sunset="4:54 pm"/>
     </channel>
</rss>
```

when I tried to parse it using dom4j

```
 SAXReader xmlReader = createXmlReader();
 Document doc = null;
 doc = xmlReader.read( inputStream );//inputStream is input of function
 log.info(doc.valueOf("/rss/channel/yweather:location/@city"));

 private SAXReader createXmlReader() {
    Map<String,String> uris = new HashMap<String,String>();
    uris.put( "yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" );
    uris.put( "geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" );

    DocumentFactory factory = new DocumentFactory();
    factory.setXPathNamespaceURIs( uris );

    SAXReader xmlReader = new SAXReader();
    xmlReader.setDocumentFactory( factory );
    return xmlReader;
}
```

But I got nothing in cmd but when I print doc.asXML(), my XML structure print correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You have an undeclared namespace prefix, both in the XML and in your XPath.

Add an appropriate `xmlns:yweather` declaration to your XML, and use [setNamespaceURIs](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/XPath.html#setNamespaceURIs%28java.util.Map%29) to make it available to your XPath.

Comment: This is the URL that I get this XML from:
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=615702&u=c

Comment: So, there is an namespace declaration in the original XML, but you still don't make the prefix `yweather:` available to your XPath.  What happens when you fix that?

Comment: There is two namespaces in XML (as you can see if you click on this link  weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=615702&u=c)
I add both of them :
 uris.put( "yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" );
     uris.put( "geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" );

Comment: And did that fix it, or are you still struggling?

Comment: No Im still struggling!:(
I changed my Weather API to this
http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=c3a35b2b0d124616120912&q=tehran%20iran&num_of_days=4&format=xml
but still I can't parse it with dom4j

Answer (score 0):

@D3GAN Everything you wrote is fine. No issue with the code. I just tried it .The problem is you DONT have all the necessary libraries in your code .

You should add jaxen library to your class path you are probably getting a NoClassdefFoundError. The original [dom4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.zip/download) distribution contains jaxen.jar (in dependancies folder).

I made the same mistake. I just added dom4j and the code didnt work . I was getting document empty. But when I added jaxen dependancy it started working fine.

If you dont know how to install JAR files you can go here :
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29